# how to handle empty tag in xml response

Tags: android

In my xml there can be empty tags like

The problem is that when I parse the xml, I am getting null pointer exception when I reach this line in the xml. 
How should I check tags like this in my parsing file? Please help me out.

Comment: which type of parsing method are you using ?

Comment: i m using dom parser for php webservice. and find response in one tag </title>..bro

Answer (score 0):

add **null** check in your code...like below...

```
if(employees.item(k).getFirstChild() != null) {
    employees.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
}
```